# SSE Loading & Adding

Tags: c, x86, sse, simd, intrinsics

Assume I have two vectors represented by two arrays of type `double`, each of size 2. I'd like to add corresponding positions. So assume vectors `i0` and `i1`, I'd like to add `i0[0] + i1[0]` and `i0[1] + i1[1]` together.

Since the type is `double`, I would need two registers. The trick would be to put `i0[0]` and `i1[0]` , and `i0[1]` and `i1[1]` in another and just add the register with itself.

My question is, if I call `_mm_load_ps(i0[0])` and then `_mm_load_ps(i1[0])`, will that place them in the lower and upper 64-bits separately, or will it replace the register with the second `load`? How would I place both doubles in the same register, so I can call `add_ps` after?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think what you want is this:

```
double i0[2];
double i1[2];

__m128d x1 = _mm_load_pd(i0);
__m128d x2 = _mm_load_pd(i1);
__m128d sum = _mm_add_pd(x1, x2);
// do whatever you want to with "sum" now
```

When you do a `_mm_load_pd`, it puts the first double into the lower 64 bits of the register and the second into the upper 64 bits. So, after the loads above, `x1` holds the two `double` values `i0[0]` and `i0[1]` (and similar for `x2`). The call to `_mm_add_pd` vertically adds the corresponding elements in `x1` and `x2`, so after the addition, `sum` holds `i0[0] + i1[0]` in its lower 64 bits and `i0[1] + i1[1]` in its upper 64 bits.

**Edit:** I should point out that there is no benefit to using `_mm_load_pd` instead of `_mm_load_ps`. As the function names indicate, the `pd` variety explicitly loads two packed doubles and the `ps` version loads four packed single-precision floats. Since these are purely bit-for-bit memory moves and they both use the SSE floating-point unit, there is no penalty to using `_mm_load_ps` to load in `double` data. And, there is a benefit to `_mm_load_ps`: its instruction encoding is one byte shorter than `_mm_load_pd`, so it is more efficient from an instruction cache sense (and potentially instruction decoding; I'm not an expert on all of the intricacies of modern x86 processors). The above code using `_mm_load_ps` would look like:

```
double i0[2];
double i1[2];

__m128d x1 = (__m128d) _mm_load_ps((float *) i0);
__m128d x2 = (__m128d) _mm_load_ps((float *) i1);
__m128d sum = _mm_add_pd(x1, x2);
// do whatever you want to with "sum" now
```

There is no function implied by the casts; it simply makes the compiler reinterpret the SSE register's contents as holding doubles instead of floats so that it can be passed into the double-precision arithmetic function `_mm_add_pd`.

Comment: You can certainly use `_mm_load_ps`, but you risk slower performance on a hypothetical future processor which is designed in such a fashion that there is a domain-bypass penalty between single- and double-precision floating point operations.  I know of no plans for such a processor, but that's not to say that one won't ever be implemented; that's why there are distinct load operations.  It's a remote possibility, admittedly, but why risk it?

Comment: I agree that there is a risk of performance deterioration on a future processor. I would suggest that one consider (i.e. measure) any performance benefit to be obtained by using `MOVPS` instead of `MOVPD` on an application-specific basis. If there's a benefit to using it today, and there is no indication of a looming architecture that would have a penalty for doing so, I would do it. Loads like these could easily be abstracted in tandem to allow automatic switch to a different implementation in the future.

Comment: IMO you shouldn't have to mess with `_mm_castps_pd` in intrinsics source: using faster equivalent instructions is the reason we have compilers in the first place.  It's a missed optimization for a compiler to ever emit `movupd` or `movapd` instead of `movups` / `movaps`.  (Or a `movsd` store (not load) instead of `movlps`).  But in practice we have compilers that fail to do these optimizations.  Fortunately(?) with AVX this finally goes away; even SSE1 instructions are stuck with a 2-byte VEX prefix, so SSE1 through SSE3 instructions are all the same length (except for immediates or xmm8..15)

Answer (score 3):

The `_ps` prefix is an abbreviation for *"packed single"*, meaning it is for use with single-precision floating point, not double-precision.

Instead, you want `_mm_load_pd()`.  This function takes a 16-byte aligned pointer to the first member of an array of two `double`s, and load them both.  So you would use this like so:

```
__m128d v0 = _mm_load_pd(i0);
__m128d v1 = _mm_load_pd(i1);

v0 = _mm_add_pd(v0, v1);
```

Comment: `_mm_load_ps` can in fact be used with double-precision values (and there are benefits to doing so); see my answer.