# Loading unaligned doubles into _m128d register

Tags: c++, c, assembly, simd, intrinsics

I'm very new to SIMD so I apologize if this happens to be a trivial question.

I have a class which contains (*amongst other things*) two doubles. I want to use these two doubles and load them into a `__m128d` register so I can perform some arithmetic operations. I.e. Say I have instances `inst1` and `inst2` of my class. I now want to add `inst1.double1` and `inst1.double2` to my first `__m128d` register, and `inst2.double1` and `inst2.double2` to my second `__m128d` register (*in that order in the registers*). How can I go about doing this?

Comment: Does [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9255252/2065121) help?

Comment: Just use _mm_set_pd(inst1.double1, inst1.double2)

Answer (score 1):

You can use _mm_loadu_pd.

See the explanation at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1bwk03a%28v=vs.90%29.aspx